# how to subset pandas dataframe on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
 buyer_id meal_type
    139       Veg
    140    NonVeg
    140       Veg
     36    NonVeg
     79       Veg
     79    NonVeg
     79    NonVeg
     72    NonVeg
     72    NonVeg
     65    NonVeg
     65       Veg
```

Now I want all the `buyer_id` which has only `Veg` as a meal type,all the `buyer_id` which has `Veg and NonVeg` as meal type and all the `buyer_id` which has only `NonVeg` as a meal type.

so,

```
139 Veg
140 Veg and NonVeg
36  NonVeg
79  Veg and NonVeg
```

and so on. I am doing the following in Python to get all the buyer ids that have `Veg`, `NonVeg` or both.

```
segments_data.buyer_id[segments_data['meal_type']=='Veg' &      
segments_data['meal_type']=='NonVeg']
```

But It doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping by `buyer_id` and converting `meal_type` into a set works:

```
>>> df.groupby('buyer_id')['meal_type'].apply(set).str.join(' and ')

    buyer_id
36             NonVeg
65     Veg and NonVeg
72             NonVeg
79     Veg and NonVeg
139               Veg
140    Veg and NonVeg
Name: meal_type, dtype: object
```

Comment: Muller  Awesome. Thanks alot.. Solved my problem.